# Why does it only change the last string in the list? (For-loop) python

Tags: python, datetime

```
a =['10-Sep-12','11-Sep-12','12-Sep-12','13-Sep-12','14-Sep-12','15-Sep-12','16-Sep-12','17- Sep-12','18-Sep-12','19-Sep-12','20-Sep-12','21-Sep-12','22-Sep-12','23-Sep-12']

for i in range (len(a)):
   date = datetime.strptime(a[i], "%d-%b-%y")
```

Why this code only change datetime format for the last string of the list only?

```
print (date)
Output : 2012-09-23 00:00:00
```

How can I fix this code?

Comment: you iterate over list and when the loop ends `date` holds the result from last element of the original list. That said, don't use `range(len())`, iterate over list elements. For what you want to do, just use list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing `date` outside the `for` loop that's why you are getting the only the last value.

Do this and you'll see that each string got converted to `datetime`.

```
a =['10-Sep-12','11-Sep-12','12-Sep-12','13-Sep-12','14-Sep-12','15-Sep-12','16-Sep-12','17-Sep-12','18-Sep-12','19-Sep-12','20-Sep-12','21-Sep-12','22-Sep-12','23-Sep-12']

for i in range (len(a)):
  date = datetime.strptime(a[i], "%d-%b-%y")
  print(date)
```

Whenever you run a loop the value of the variable changes each iteration. If you print that variable outside the loop, it'll only print the last value of the variable. In your case being the value stored inside it in the 14th iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Because you only print date once after the entire process is complete. If you put the print statement in the loop it will print all 12 dates.

Answer (score 0):

The code is setting he value of *date* in each iteration of the loop, so when the loop is completed, *date* will hold the last value it was set to.

If you print out its value within the loop you'll see the value changing for each execution.

```
import datetime

a =['10-Sep-12','11-Sep-12','12-Sep-12','13-Sep-12','14-Sep-12','15-Sep-12','16-Sep-12','17-Sep-12','18-Sep-12','19-Sep-12','20-Sep-12','21-Sep-12','22-Sep-12','23-Sep-12']

for i in range (len(a)):
   date = datetime.datetime.strptime(a[i], "%d-%b-%y")
   print(date)
```